# Exporting work item definition fails in Azure Devops 2019

Tags: tfs, azure-devops, azure-devops-extensions, azure-devops-server-2019, azure-devops-server

I get the following error when I try to export a work item witadmin in Azure DevOps 2019

```
witadmin exportwitd /collection:<URL to team project> /p:AutoRI /n:Bug /f:<PathToExportedxml>\exported1.xml
```

> The feature is disabled. Contact your Azure DevOps Server
>   administrator. Process Id: 6483e73b-0c68-416d-88d8-9aff672828c7,
>   Project Id: ceec55cd-a350-499f-82e2-47245c379a05

I am the Administrators of the project and I have the necessary authority.

Can some one please let me know how I can enable the feature? There is no documentation around this problem.

My permission is shown in the image:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not about basic agile or customized, actually it's related to process model you are using.

As declared clearly in [witAdmin command line reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/reference/witadmin/witadmin-customize-and-manage-objects-for-tracking-work?view=azure-devops-2019&viewFallbackFrom=azure-devops):

> With witadmin, you can modify XML definition files to **support the
>   On-premises XML process model**. For an overview of process models and
>   what is supported, see Customize your work tracking experience.

To customize **inherited processes**, you just need to do it in the web portal. It's no need and also not able to export work item by using witadmin  command.

More details, please kindly review our official [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/settings/work/manage-process?view=azure-devops) here.

Hope this is clearly.

Comment: Thank you for the link to the documentation. However, I need to be able to export my modified process templates for backup purposes, in case I need to restore them after a catastrophic failure (or migrate them to a new collection). I've invested much time and effort into my customizations and I'm uncomfortable with the idea of them being siloed in a single collection/project. How can I enable this feature, so that I can export my templates using [this script](https://github.com/microsoft/process-customization-scripts/blob/master/Export/ExportProjectTemplate.ps1)? I'm using ADS 2022.

Comment: p.s. I'm using the Inherited process model. Is there a way to export (back up) my painstakingly crafted customizations?

Answer (score 2):

This error can be if you are trying to export from collection with Inherited processes. I have checked on my azure devops server:

1. First collection with xml processes: waitadmin exports wi definition
2. Second collection with inherited processes: the same error